# Move files created (Not modified) over an hour ago

Tags: forfiles

I am trying to move files that were created more than 30 days ago to a new directory to manage disk space on a server.

The command below won't work as this uses the "Date Modified" time and not the "Date Created" file:
[Example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOL34.png)

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Currently this is what I have tried:
forfiles -p "D:\Data" -s -m *.* -d -30 -c "cmd /c move @file "E:\Data\Backup""